is it possible to use react 17.0.2 with "next": "^14.0.0" "react-17": "npm:react@17.0.2",
i can see "react-17": "npm:react@17.0.2",in next dependency package.json,  is it possible to use react 17.0.2 with "next": "^14.0.0", i tried to use but getting error

Could not resolve dependency

Package.json
{
  "name": "web",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": " web application",
  "author": "@abc.com",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next -p 3000",
    "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start -p 8080"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ant-design/plots": "^1.2.5",
    "@dds/components": "^2.37.1",
    "axios": "^1.7.2",
    "crypto-js": "^4.2.0",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "next": "^14.0.0",
    "next-pwa": "^5.6.0",
    "next-redux-wrapper": "^7.0.5",
    "rc-steps": "^3.6.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-alert": "^7.0.3",
    "react-alert-template-basic": "^1.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dropzone": "^14.2.3",
    "react-moment": "^1.1.2",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.1",
    "react-table": "^7.8.0",
    "react-tooltip": "^4.2.21",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "rsuite": "^5.13.1",
    "semver": "^7.5.4",
    "xlsx": "file:xlsx-0.20.2.tgz"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "sass": "^1.69.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "18.20.3"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "ansi-regex": "3.0.1",
    "semver": "7.5.4",
    "postcss": "8.4.38",
    "serialize-javascript": "6.0.2",
    "uglify-js": "3.14.3"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "postcss": "8.4.38",
    "ejs": "3.1.10",
    "follow-redirects": "^1.15.6",
    "xlsx": "file:xlsx-0.20.2.tgz"
  }
}

Error:
❯ npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: web@2.0.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^18.2.0" from next@14.2.5
npm ERR! node_modules/next
npm ERR!   next@"^14.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /home/.npm/_logs/2024-08-14T09_50_35_970Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/.npm/_logs/2024-08-14T09_50_35_970Z-debug-0.log


It should work: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-version Can you provide a minimal package.json to reproduce the issue?

@NotX i added package.json,
i am new to web development, i can see 3 down vote, not sure any issue with the question

Probably b/c the issue wasn't reproducible without further information. The package.json is a good start, but next would be to create a minimal example - just remove all dependencies you can without the error disappearing. (I also formatted your post a bit to make it more readable).

Please provide the complete, verbatim error message. It probably contains peer react@"^18.2.0" from next@14.2.5. That means, next@14.2.5 expects a React version >= 18.2.0 and < 18.3.0 (or < 19.0.0, not 100% sure). But at least, it doesn't work with React 17.x.x

I've added my error message. Please correct it, if you get a different message.

According to https://semver.npmjs.com/, ^18.2.0 means >= 18.2.0 and < 19.0.0.

I've checked. The Next.js documentation claims it works with older React versions:
At the same time, we can see Next.js v14.2.5 is defining React v18 as peer dependency.
This looks like a contradiction to me. But maybe the documentation is correct and Next.js actually can handle older versions of React, and maybe detects internally which version is available - I didn't check the code for that. So you can opt for this optimistic route, hope that the statement from the documentation is true and just run npm install with the suggested flags, so either npm install --force or npm install --legacy-peer-deps, and hope for the best. You can even override these peer dependencies in you package.json by adding
"overrides": {
    "next": {
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
    }
}

But as I said, despite from what the documentation claims I'ld be careful with enforcing an older React version.
